# How to make a sine wave circle in GLSL

Tags: opengl, glsl, fragment-shader

I'm trying to distort the drawing of a circle with a sine wave so that it looks like this in an OpenGL Shader.

[image]

I've found many examples of using the `length` of the radius from a center point to draw a circle, but I have not been able to figure out how to modulate this with a sine wave to distort the circle radius. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you know how to generate such a thing *without* a shader? If not, then you need to figure that out. Once done, you can work on putting it into a shader. And either way, it wouldn't be a *fragment* shader.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the angle from a fragment to the center as input for the `sin` function and add the result to the length.

[Example:](http://glslsandbox.com/e#33107.0)

```
vec2 position = gl_FragCoord.xy - resolution / 2.0;
float color = smoothstep(2.0, 4.0, abs(length(position) - 50.0 
    + sin(atan(position.y, position.x) * 4.0 - 3.141 / 2.0) * 7.0));
gl_FragColor = vec4(vec3(color), 1.0 );
```